# Want to merge Full Date with given time in Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

I have time in string format.
Like: `23:00:00`
This is saved in `time="23:00:00"`
I want a string like this: `August 16,2017 23:00:00` **where today's date will append to the given time to a string** in ANGULAR2 Typescript without using any pipe.

Comment: looks for me like yu using something the wrong way...

Comment: Actual i want the todays date with the given time in a string. So the thing is the time is comming from the database.

Comment: are you using php? you can also use ng-init to set js variables combined with any rendering engine (php, c# etc..) 

use moment js to parse the string as date object and then add the time to today()

Comment: I added the typescript tag to make it more relevant, so stop with the javascript answers. There are probably an equivalent to the Date parser of javascript in Typescript, you should probably look for that.

Answer (score -1):

You can use moment to accomplish that, please check the link below:
https://momentjs.com/docs/